# Regex (Groups) - validation for word

Tags: regex

I request your help with the following expression that does not meet all the patterns, the expression that I built is the following:
Pattern: `^(\w{1,}\W?\w{1,})\s([\w].*)\s([\d.?]{1,})\s([\d.?]{1,})\s([\d.?]{1,})$`

- Group 1: 1G701−2LF00
- Group 2: FUEL PUMP ASSY
- Group 3: 6
- Group 4: 102.40
- Group 5: 614.40

*Lines:*

```
1G701−2LF00 FUEL PUMP ASSY 6 102.40 614.40
32114−40K00 COV,BRG PINION 8 17.85 142.80
32357−L1005 WASH, 10 7.72 77.20
38120−1320A BRG PINION REAR 4 21.62 86.48
48527−FS001 LINK−RR LIFT ASSY 4 64.39 257.56
17960−GU60A DIAPHRAGM ASSY 2 25.69 51.38
22B55−22011 CABLE ACCEL 2 36.14 72.28
31516−40K00 PISTON SEAL RING 2 26.15 52.30
31715−L1001 PACKING 8 3.47 27.76
31924−40K01 O−RING 10 1.49 14.90
32112−11H00 GSKT,OIL PUMP 2 6.36 12.72
32162−40K00 PACKING 8 9.44 75.52
38320−60K00 PKG,AXLE HSG 2 17.49 34.98
65320−FB401 STAY ASSY−TOP 2 6.85 13.70
96303−GL10A MIRROR−OUTSIDE,RH 2 31.02 62.04
58099−FA31B PACK KIT−LIFT CYL 1 93.70 93.70
58699−GG01A PACK KIT−CYL 2 60.77 121.54
62170−12731 PULLEY 1 10.18 10.18
691H2−00029 SEAL KIT REACH CYLINDER 2 120.53 241.06
NF91A24−41700 GASKET 1 10.86 10.86
1G6282TF00 VALVE 10 12.62 126.20
2G112−5MF01 BELT−FAN 3 26.75 80.25
2G245−6NF01 CABLE SET 6 62.07 372.42
277P8−22052 ROLLER END 119.0 2 47.90 95.80
2G301−6NF01 ALTERNATOR 1 475.53 475.53
SLIFT−16405−01H FUEL FILTER 60 7.80 468.00
```

*Expected:*

```
1G701−2LF00 FUEL PUMP ASSY 6 102.40 614.40 -- Passed
32114−40K00 COV,BRG PINION 8 17.85 142.80 -- Passed
32357−L1005 WASH, 10 7.72 77.20 -- Passed
38120−1320A BRG PINION REAR 4 21.62 86.48 -- Passed
48527−FS001 LINK−RR LIFT ASSY 4 64.39 257.56 -- Passed
17960−GU60A DIAPHRAGM ASSY 2 25.69 51.38 -- Passed
22B55−22011 CABLE ACCEL 2 36.14 72.28 -- Passed
31516−40K00 PISTON SEAL RING 2 26.15 52.30 -- Passed
31715−L1001 PACKING 8 3.47 27.76 -- Passed
31924−40K01 O−RING 10 1.49 14.90 -- Passed
32112−11H00 GSKT,OIL PUMP 2 6.36 12.72 -- Passed
32162−40K00 PACKING 8 9.44 75.52 -- Passed
38320−60K00 PKG,AXLE HSG 2 17.49 34.98 -- Passed
65320−FB401 STAY ASSY−TOP 2 6.85 13.70 -- Passed
96303−GL10A MIRROR−OUTSIDE,RH 2 31.02 62.04 -- Passed
58099−FA31B PACK KIT−LIFT CYL 1 93.70 93.70 -- Passed
58699−GG01A PACK KIT−CYL 2 60.77 121.54 -- Passed
62170−12731 PULLEY 1 10.18 10.18 -- Passed
691H2−00029 SEAL KIT REACH CYLINDER 2 120.53 241.06 -- Passed
NF91A24−41700 GASKET 1 10.86 10.86 -- Passed
1G6282TF00 VALVE 10 12.62 126.20 -- Passed
2G112−5MF01 BELT−FAN 3 26.75 80.25 -- Passed
2G245−6NF01 CABLE SET 6 62.07 372.42 -- Passed
277P8−22052 ROLLER END 119.0 2 47.90 95.80 -- Passed
2G301−6NF01 ALTERNATOR 1 475.53 475.53 -- Passed
SLIFT−16405−01H FUEL FILTER 60 7.80 468.00 -- Not Pass
```

Maybe there could be more characters or `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the pattern `\w{1,}\W?\w{1,}` matches 1 or more word chars, an optional non word character and then again 1 or more word chars. Maybe is it not intended, but note that the `\W` is optional and there should be at least 2 word characters.

In the last example string `SLIFT−16405−01H` there are 2 hyphens, but the pattern can not match `−01H` as the `\W` followed by word characters is not repeated and will only match once.

---

In the example data, the first part only contains `-` and if that is the only non word character, `\W` is a broad match. You could instead match the `-` or use `[^\w\s]`

To match all lines in the example data:

```
^(\w+(?:−\w+)*)\s(\w.*?)\s([\d.?]+)\s([\d.?]+)\s([\d.?]+)$
```

- `^` start of string
- `(\w+(?:−\w+)*)\s` Capture 1+ word chars, and optionally repeat a `-` and again 1+ word chars
- `(\w.*?)\s` Capture a single word char followed by as least as possible (non greedy) until the first whitespace char
- `([\d.?]+)\s` Capture 1+ times a digit, `.` or `?` and match a whitespace char
- `([\d.?]+)\s` Same as previous
- `([\d.?]+)` Same as previous without the whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rArUsN/1)

Or a bit more specific matching digits with an optional decimal part and repeating non word chars except a whitspace using `[^\w\s]`

```
^(\w+(?:[^\w\s]\w+)*)\s(\w.*?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1aR5P/1)